# i made an gusse counter with while loop for 3 trys and the counter stuck at 2

Tags: python, while-loop

```
import random
import itertools as it


def guessthenumber():
    play = input("do you want to play ?\nanswer yes or no :")
    while play != "yes" :
        if play == "no" :
            quit()
        else:
            guessthenumber()
        break


guessthenumber()
answer = random.randint(1, 5)


def random_func():
    gusse = int(input("choose a number between 0 and 10"))
    count = 3
    while gusse != answer and count != 0 :
        count -= 1
        print(count)
        print("wrong")
        random_func()
        break
    random_func()
    print("won")
```

Why does the guess count stop at 2 even with for loop?

Comment: You are using recursion instead of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is as pointed out by @quamrana. When you call `random_func` you are adding a new stack frame that has a new `count` variable initialized to 3, so it immediately decrements, but then you add another call to `random_func`. You never return and pop this call off the stack, so there is no way to continue.

I don't see why ask if the caller wants to play. If it is the only thing the program does, running it is a pretty good indication. Also, is "gusse" a thing or just a misspelling of "guess".

You should avoid using `quit()` unless you are in an interpreter. You can use [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), but in simple scenarios like this, returning and finishing the program is more simple.

Consider the following implementation with some slight improvements.

```py
import random


def start(answer, tries):
    while tries:  # Continue while tries remain.
        guess = int(input("choose a number between 0 and 10: "))
        if guess == answer:
            print("won")
            return  # Just return from the function.
        tries -= 1  # Otherwise, decrement and continue.
        print(f"wrong; tries remaining: {tries}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = random.randint(1, 5)
    start(answer, 3)  # Begin the guessing part of the game.
```

Comment: thank you that was very helpful i add the ask for playing cause im just practicing and want to develop my range and yes gusse is a misspelling of guess hhhh i want to know one thing what is the purpose of the line "if __name__ == "__main__" : " cause it seems the program run fine without it .

Comment: @TUSKACT4: [Here is an excellent answer on if __name__ == "__main__"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/2081835). Basically, it prevents this code from running if the module is imported.